# Navigate Bootstrap Datepicker with Previous and Next Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

How can I get Previous and Next Button functionality to Navigate Bootstrap Datepicker with jquery as in fig bellow

[image]

I have tried like

```
 function PrevNext(isnextbtn)
    {
        var date = new Date();
        var searchdate = new Date();

        if ($('#txtDate').val().length > 0){
            date = new Date($('#txtDate').val());
        }
        else {
            date = new Date('@DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()');
        }

        alert(date);

        if (isnextbtn == 1) {
            searchdate = date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1, 1);
        }
        else {
            searchdate = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1, 1);
        }

        $('#txtDate').datepicker('setDate', searchdate);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve my Issue with following code; Please update me if there is another better way to achieve this.

Note: My Date is in dd/MM/yyyy format

```
function PrevNext(isnext)
    {
        var dateString = $("#txtDate").val().split("/");
        var actualDate = new Date(dateString[2], dateString[1] - 1, dateString[0]);
        var newDate = new Date();
        if(isnext == 1)
            newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth(), actualDate.getDate() + 1);
        else
            newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth(), actualDate.getDate() - 1);
        $('#txtDate').datepicker('setDate', newDate);
    }
```